# How to enable AJAX for Wordpress WP Page-Navi Plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm following [Pippin Williamson's tutorial](http://www.wpmods.com/easily-ajax-wordpress-pagination/) on how to AJAX wordpress pagination for a [kids toys site](http://www.escalamadrid.com/kalimba2/) that I am creating.

Using the following javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.pagination_container a').live('click', function(e)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('.content').fadeOut(500).load(link + '.content .prodlist_container', function() {
    jQuery('.content').fadeIn(500); });
    });
});
```

... i have managed to get the pagination to work but am experiencing the following issues:

- Long delay in loading the paginated pages (considering the small image size)
- all product images have strangely been given the hover state (blue graphic)
- The pagination buttons no longer function correctly.

Any suggestions / advice appreciated as I've been going round in circles for a while.

Here's the HTML / PHP in case that helps:

```
<div class="content">


        <div class="breadpage_container group">

            <div id="breadcrumb_container">


            </div><!-- end breadcrumb_container -->

            <div class="pagination_container">


            </div><!-- end pagination container -->

        </div><!--end breadpage_container -->

        <div class="prodlist_container">

            <ul class="products group">

            <!-- loop to show products list -->

            <?php $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'products',
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => 'DES',
                'posts_per_page' => 8,
                'paged' => get_query_var ('page'),
                'post_parent' => $parent
                ); ?>

            <?php query_posts($args); ?>

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <li>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="product_image">
                        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ProductImage', true);?>
                        <span class="overlay"></span>
                    </a>

                    <h3 class="product_tit"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
                    <p class="price_tag"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ProductPrice', true); ?></p>

                </li>   

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else :?>

                <p>There are no products to display</p>

            <?php endif; ?>


            </ul>   



        <div class="breadpage_container group" id="lower_breadpage_container">

            <div class="pagination_container">

                <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>                  

            </div><!-- end pagination container -->

        </div><!--end breadpage_container -->   

        </div><!-- prodlist_container -->   


</div><!-- end content -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a couple of different issues here. First of all, it looks like there's a small error in your `load()` function. When loading page fragments, you need to pass in the URL followed by the selectors but your string doesn't have a space between the URL and the selectors. It should read:

```
jQuery('.content').fadeOut(500).load(link + ' .content .prodlist_container', function() {
```

That should solve the slow loading and the pagination problem (at the moment it's probably trying to parse a bunch of `.prodlist_container` divs and getting confused).

As for the hover problem, my guess is you've initiated this in jQuery on `$(document).ready()` but this isn't triggered when a page fragment is loaded via AJAX. You'll probably have to add the stuff you've currently got under `$(document).ready()` to a page initiation function and call this when `load()` completes, like this:

```
jQuery('.content').fadeOut(500).load(link + ' .content .prodlist_container', function() {
    pageInit(); // New function with content of $(document).ready()
    jQuery('.content').fadeIn(500); });
});
```

Remember, you'll have to call `pageInit()` in `$(document).ready()` now though!

Comment: Many thanks Mr. JunkMyFunk - I added the space as you spotteed which made the pagination work and created a separate pageinit function to be called every time the paginated link is triggered. It's now working perfectly. I'd give you a green tick but can´t until i have 15 reputation points :( - Many thanks for your help gentleman.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly altered version of @JunkMyFunk's code did the trick for me:

```
//AJAX PAGINATION
jQuery('.wp-pagenavi a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#property-results').load(link + ' #property-results', function() {
        jQuery('#property-results').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the pictures load fast enough but the delay could be because youre loading the jquery pagination plugin and that might add a few extra seconds.

I think for the hoover problem you need to reset the event every time a new page is loaded since the < li > of the 2nd and 3rd page arent loaded when you do the $(document).ready() ..

1,2,3 pagination buttons work fine for me, but the >> stops on the second page. You need to update the href in that button everytime you load a new page but I dont know how that pagination plugin works...